# Merging shapefiles in a folder using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis, qgis-processing, merge

I was reading the QGIS Python Programming Cookbook (page 74) trying to learn how to merge shapefiles because I need to do it for what I'm doing.
I was using their example just to try it out though.

I would like to know if there's any way to merge all the shapefiles in a folder together to make one shapefile.

Theses are the files in my folder:

```
footprints_ne.dbf
footprints_ne.shp
footprints_ne.shx
footprints_nw.dbf
footprints_nw.shp
footprints_nw.shx
footprints_se.dbf
footprints_se.shp
footprints_se.shx
footprints_sw.dbf
footprints_sw.shp
footprints_sw.shx
```

And this is my code:

```
import os
import glob
import urllib
import sys
import zipfile
import processing


pth = "C:/Users/myself/Desktop/qgis_data/tiled_footprints/"

files = glob.glob(pth + "*.shp")

out = pth + "merged.shp"

processing.runandload("saga:mergeshapeslayers", files.pop(0), ";".join(files), out)
```

For some reason it gives me an error complaining about my algorithm but I'm just following the book. I am new to programming.

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: Which QGIS and _Processing_ plugin version are you using? In the latest versions, the algorithm is now currently called `saga:mergelayers`. The parameters for this have also slightly changed: [input, source info, match field names, output]. So you should probably use something like: `processing.runandload("saga:mergelayers", files, True, True, out)`